# Is there a continuous highway or high-speed rail between Estonia to Poland?

Tags: schengen, driving, poland, high-speed-rail, estonia

Since all the Baltic states and Poland are now part of the Schengen Area, Estonia has a contiguous connection to the rest of the EU. Is there a single continuous highway or high-speed rail between Estonia to the rest of the EU through Poland that can be used for land travel?

Comment: What do you mean continuous?  There is a way to get to Poland through Lithuania.

Comment: A single highway that you can drive without taking an exit, or rail where you can travel without getting out.

Comment: There is not.  You can simply Google Map it.

Comment: Are you referring to a [motorway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled-access_highway)?

Comment: Not even long term plans include one AFAIK. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan-European_corridors#/media/File:Pan-European_corridors.svg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put: no, there is no such road (expressway or motorway) nor high-speed rail through Poland in that direction

Why do you ask for "continuous" one?

Comment: OP surely asks for "continuous" for the same reason continuous ones are built. Because they're faster and more direct.

Comment: I understand that, but knowing exactly what he meant, I could try to give better advice on alternative routes

Answer (score 7):

The understanding of the world "highway" differs from culture to culture. There is the [E67](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_route_E67), is that enough for you or are you asking for a more substantial road?

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Exactly a comment

Comment: It's not really *just* a comment since the answer of route E67 is offered as a continuous highway, and also questioning OP's question precision.

Comment: Perfect answer to the question, thanks.  Upvoted.

Comment: the thing is that E67 is not a highway in a sense as a western european person could expect

Comment: @KamilMikolajczyk, hence my question mark. Not a German Autobahn, but Germans are in love with their cars.